# How to Optimize API Calls in Next.js ISR for Shared Header and Footer Components Across Multiple Pages?

Tags: next.js

I have 30 pages on my next.js application and all the pages have common header and footer component and this header and footer component rendering the data which is comming from an api which is `getHeaderFooterData()` and i am using this api in `getStaticProps()` function for each single page so it means on build time for each pages `getHeaderFooterData()` api will get call for 30 times which not seems optimized way i think which will leads to time taking build process

i just expecting that is there any way to call `getHeaderFooterData()` api only once and used the data accross all the pages at build time it self